# Javascript : Image Resizing in Chrome using mouse

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, resize

How can I resize images in Chrome using a mouse? i.e. when you stretch an image using a mouse.

Comment: @Mickey By binding mousedown and mousemove handlers...

Comment: Also, what does it have to do with chrome?

Comment: @OmerPT in a contenteditable iframe ,by default chorome doesnot support image resizing using mousedown/mousemove event.u need a write script to handle this ..

Comment: @Sime Vidas That I know buddy. I have to bind image with these two events but what next ? how the image size will chane in chrome in a contenteditable region say iframe ..?

Comment: @Mickey You can change the size of the image by setting its `.style.width` property to a value in px (for instance `'200px'`).

Comment: @Mickey I would make you a working demo, but I'll have to go buy a Wii Remote Plus `:)` (my cousin is coming over later). Maybe later today or tomorrow, if you remind me...

Answer (score 0):

Someone have already made a jQuery plugin for this purpose : http://www.editorboost.net/webkitresize